# How to Hide a asp:Control without using CSS or ServerSide scripting or setting its properties

Tags: asp.net

i am trying to hide asp:button without using CSS or serverside Coding or setting its property. How can i hide this control on loading

Comment: doesn't leave you with many options.  jQuery is the way to go.

Comment: Why so little options to do so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap it with a hidden `span` or a hidden `div`, or an asp hidden panel.